# CLLocationmanager delegate method is not working in xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-location, xcode6

i am created new project in Xcode6 and added the old files to this project(old files is created in xcode5) ,But whats happening is everything working fine, but 
"didUpdateToLocation" delegate method is not calling, i also used "didUpdateLocations" delegate method but both are not working.Code i have used from old file but the core location framework has been added from xcode6 ,I don't know what i am missing please anyone guide me to get a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're testing this on iOS 8 device / Simulator, old location code may not work because of the way the iOS 8 handles Location Services permission access. As of current iOS 8 beta, you need to use new `-requestWhenInUseAuthorization` method:

```
- (void)updateCurrentLocation {

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

The user prompt contains the text from the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your app’s Info.plist file, and the presence of that key is required when calling this method.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We use your location to find places near you.</string>
```

Comment: +1 I did not see this updated in the docs.