# Core Location delegate methods not getting called in iOS 8.3 Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, core-location, ios8.3, xcode6.3.1

I am trying to get the user's current location using the Core Location Framework in Xcode 6.3.1, I did following things:

1. Added **Core Location Framework** under **Target**-> **General**-> **Linked Frameworks & Libraries**
2. My **ViewController.h** file is as shown below,

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLatitude;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLongitude;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblAddress;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

   @end
   ```
3. My ViewController.m file is as shown below,

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {

   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

   self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
       NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
       if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] || [self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {
       if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
           [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
       } else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
           [self.locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
       } else {
           NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
       }
   }
   }
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }

   #pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
       NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
       UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [errorAlert show];
   }

   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
   {
       NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
       CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

       if (currentLocation != nil) {
           lblLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
           lblLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
       }
   }
   @end
   ```

I had also added the following keys in my info.plist file

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

[image: plist image]

Checked everything given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971981/cllocationmanager-delegate-method-is-not-working-in-xcode6), [here](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/), [here](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/), and a lot more list

So, is anyone having a solution for this issue, kindly help. Have lost my mind searching for this for the whole day.

Comment: The values for those usage description is empty. Are you sure you've put them in? Also why do you have two usage description?

Comment: @VinhNguyen I had tried by putting values in that too, but that does not have any affect, & by keeping only NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription then also that doesn't work for me. Tried that too...

Comment: Try remove the if block `if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined &&....` and simply call either `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` on your `locationManager` instance

Comment: Tried, but still delegate in not called, not even got the prompt message.

Comment: What's in your `IS_OS_8_OR_LATER` macro? Try remove that too.

Comment: It was to check the device version `#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)`, removed that too but no difference, same result

Comment: Sounds weird, but try delete the app and run again. And, best is to set breakpoints to see if something is missing.

Comment: Check out http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/ if you're still stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78060/discussion-between-rajat-deep-singh-and-vinh-nguyen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah! Got the solution, Here is my whole code & things added to make it working. Special thanks to @MBarton for his great help. Also Thanks to @ Vinh Nguyen for investing his precious time in solving my issue.

Added **Core Location Framework** under **Target-> General-> Linked Frameworks & Libraries**

Added in .plist file

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

See Screenshot:

[image: plist screenshot]

In my `ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

// #define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate,  CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    __weak IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationItem;
}

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

Then in `ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self setUpMap];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setUpMap
{
    mapView.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
   // if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) { 
        // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

    //View Area
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Ufff...! Got the solution after fighting with many codes since last 5 days...

Comment: Do not use `IS_OS_8_OR_LATER`. There are proper ways to check if an API is available or not.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated my code, kindly review & provide your valuable suggestions. Thanks for letting me know about this.

Comment: That's better. I'd completely remove all references to those macros from your answer.